Connect to an auto updating server using NodeJS, Electron Forge, and Vite
I have been attempting to connect to an auto-updating server. I am currently using NodeJS, NPM, Electron Forge, and Vite. I have tried to use SQL Server multiple times, but I run into a circular reference error every time. I'm looking for a solution to how I'm currently doing it or another route.
My process so far in Visual Studio Code
npm init electron-app@latest serverTest -- --template=vite
cd serverTest
npm install mssql msnodesqlv8 tedious
npm install buffer

Paste the sample code given to test:
import sql from 'mssql';
(async () => {
    try {
        // make sure that any items are correctly URL encoded in the connection string
        await sql.connect('Server=localhost,1433;Database=database;User       Id=username;Password=password;Encrypt=true')
        const result = await sql.query`select * from mytable where id = ${value}`
        console.dir(result)
     } catch (err) {
        // ... error checks
    }
})()

Then running:
npm start

results in an error:

Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
at node_modules/mssql/lib/base/connection-pool.js (

